# Disable window transitions on Windows Mobile 8 / 10

Tags: windows-mobile

When I switch between applications or go to the home screen on Windows Mobile it has a pretty elaborate transition effect from one window to the next. The screen slides out as a new one slides into the view, it takes about 250-500ms. I was wondering if this can be disabled. My favorite thing about my windows desktop computer is that it is snappy fast, and was hoping to make things just as snappy fast on the phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not disable the animation effects when switching between apps - because this time is actually used to load / "unfreeze" the app and make it usable as soon as it is fully displayed. 
The animation basically masks the load time - without it the system would feel even less snappy.

I wasn't able to find a source specifically for Windows Phone but there's a lot of further information if you search for "perceived app responsiveness" in combination with "app page transitions".

Comment: oh well all I can hope for is that their new flagship win10 phone is faster